# standard d3 workflow and hosting solutions

Tags: d3.js

I am new to [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) and it seems like there are a lot of options when it comes to developing and hosting projects.

Options include:

- [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org)
- [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)
- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)
- [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)
- [vida.io](http://vida.io)
- etc.

I can also run a web server with python for local development, but in my case, I am not able to host my projects locally.

[bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org) is really popular, but I have run into many caching issues when using it to develop code (make a change, wait 5 mins, see the change).

At the moment, I was thinking that the best bet would be to develop locally then put the code in a gist and use [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org) to host it.

**My question is**:
Is this a fairly standard and sensible workflow for d3 and are there any other services out there that you recommend I should use instead of [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org)?

Comment: I don't think there's a "standard" workflow. Whatever works best for you really.

Comment: Thanks Lars, does the list of options pretty much cover it or would you add anything?

Comment: I think it's all there. It's of course possible that somebody prefers something else, but in terms of things that are commonly used there's pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Develop locally.**  For most D3 work you don't even need a server running, since browsers will "serve" static html, javascript, json and csv over the `file://` protocol (**EDIT**: [except Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416)).  This makes the development cycle simple, fast and easy.

**Deploy with GitHub**.  If you're just serving static pages and not hosting anything else, it's the fastest way to get something up on the web.  There are two good ways to do this:

- [Gist](https://gist.github.com) hosted, view on [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org).  This is great for little examples and one-off tricks.  The best part of this is that it just works, no configuration necessary.  Also it's neat to see the auto-generated gallery of your visualizations.
- GitHub [Pages](https://pages.github.com).  This is best for more significant projects, since you can completely customize the interface to your liking (and even use your own domain!).  Just don't forget to put a "fork me" [ribbon](https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons) in the corner.

And please do post any neat visualizations you build to the [gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)!